# Measure the time page element is visible on the page with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition

When I interact with the page, loader appears for couple of seconds, and then it disappears completely from page html.

```
<div class="loader">
<img src="/static/media/loading-anim-windmill.9f645983.gif" alt="loading"><p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

for waiting this element to appear i simply write

```
element = WebDriverWait(elem, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, val)))
```

but how do I know when did it disappear? and how do i measure this time range?

Comment: What is it loading? What's the timedelta between network requests?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus its an api request, different api endpoint in different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to `element_to_be_clickable` expected condition there are `invisibility_of_element_located` and `invisibility_of_element` expected conditions.
So, to wait for element to disappear you can do something like this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "the_css_selector")))
```

To measure the time the elements disappears you can do as following:

```py
startTime = time.time()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "the_css_selector")))
finishTime = time.time()
print(finishTime-startTime)
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants the timedelta between ... some moment in time when the loading starts, and the moment the expected element is fully visible. So maybe get the timestamp when Element A becomes visible, and then timestamp when Element B is visible.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I see OP is asking ` how do I know when did it disappear? and how do i measure this time range?` This is what I tried to answer here. But maybe I misunderstood something

Comment: I guess the OP now has a proper answer. +1.

Comment: My code is in python, but still thanks works the same as in C#.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mixed python with Java :) Now it is fixed